# Android RxJava/Gson/Retrofit return some fields as null, when they are not

Tags: android, json, rx-java, retrofit2, dagger-2

I've been studying Android for 3 weeks now and i've hit wall that i spent my whole day failing to overcome. I've set mvp project with Dagger 2, Retrofit and RxJava. Everything is working as expected, but when i make a get request, the observable i get has 2 fields that are null.

This is the json that i request (cant post links) gist.githubusercontent.com/TonyNikolov/89720ae547e479fb9e92c81ef4b33bef/raw/dcabde67e7fe9032cff702cc24f0cfe208b7402e/superheroes.json

But response observable is this http://
imgur.com/a/oHxFV

As you can see fields "imageUrl" and "secretIdentity" are null, but "name" and "id" are correct. This is for every Object.

Click [here for full github project](https://github.com/TonyNikolov/AndroidDev/tree/master/WorkshopDemo"")

This is what my NetModule looks like

```
@Module
public class NetModule {
String mBaseUrl;

public NetModule(String mBaseUrl) {
    this.mBaseUrl = mBaseUrl;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    return cache;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Gson provideGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return gsonBuilder.create();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.cache(cache);
    return client.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}

}
```

This is SuperheroesListPresenter

```
public class SuperheroesListPresenter implements    PresenterContract.SuperheroesListPresenter {

Retrofit retrofit;
ViewContract.SuperheroesList mView;

@Inject
SuperheroesListPresenter(Retrofit retrofit, ViewContract.SuperheroesList mView) {
    this.retrofit = retrofit;
    this.mView = mView;
}


@Override
public void loadSuperheroes() {
    retrofit.create(superheroService.class).getSuperheroesList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Superhero>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    mView.showComplete();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mView.showError(e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Superhero> posts) {
                    mView.showSuperheroes(posts);
                }
            });
}


private interface superheroService {
    @GET("/TonyNikolov/89720ae547e479fb9e92c81ef4b33bef/raw/dcabde67e7fe9032cff702cc24f0cfe208b7402e/superheroes.json")
    Observable<List<Superhero>> getSuperheroesList();
}
}
```

This is Superhero class

```
public class Superhero {

public String name;
public String imageUrl;
public String secretIdentity;
public int id;

Superhero(String name, String imageUrl, String secretIdentity, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.secretIdentity = secretIdentity;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.id = id;

}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSecretIdentity() {
    return this.secretIdentity;
}

public void setSecretIdentity(String secretIdentity) {
    this.secretIdentity = secretIdentity;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return this.imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

I know i should use the setters in the constructor, but i've spent 8 hours trying to deal with this problem and i changed a lot of code trying to find the problem.

Comment: Fixed it myself... The problem was with FieldNamingPolicy changed it to Identity

Comment: If you fixed it yourself please post a short answer and accept it

Comment: `GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder(); gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);` because field naming policy shouldn't say it's `secret_identity` instead of `secretIdentity`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some fields named things like `imageURL` and found that

`gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY);`

fixed the problem.